# replace values by the mean

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as follow:

```
         Col1        Price
1      Plastic        50
2        Metal        100
3      Plastic        40
```

I would like to replace values in Col1 by their means in Price, So I get:

```
         Col1       Price
1         45         50
2        100        100
3         45         40
```

I've already did :

```
df.groupby('Col1').mean()['Price']
```

But I don't know how to replace the values, maybe using map ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct- `map` can be used to do this like so:

```
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].map(df.groupby('Col1')['Price'].mean())
df
   Col1  Price
1    45     50
2   100    100
3    45     40
```

Comment: I like your answer! :) +1

Comment: @ScottBoston 1000 ways to skin a cat as they say! ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
df.assign(Col1=df.Col1.map(df.groupby('Col1').mean().squeeze()))
```

Output:

```
   Col1  Price
1    45     50
2   100    100
3    45     40
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the result directly , You can use `transform`

```
df['Col1']=df.groupby(['Col1'])['Price'].transform('mean')


   Col1  Price
0    45     50
1   100    100
2    45     40
```