# How replace largest values by mean (grouped) values

Tags: python

I have a dataframe, where I want to replace the two largest values by the mean values of that group for which this value relates. At the same time, those largest values should not be taken into account when calculating the mean values.

My code is following, however, it calculates the mean for the whole dataset (without grouping by 'group' and taking into account these largest values)

I also think that this can be done by using map(), and example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635157/replace-values-by-the-mean)

```
data = {
  "production": [420, 900, 390, 500, 555, 700],
    "group": ['A','A','A','B','B','B']
}

data = pd.DataFrame(data)

mask = data[data['production'].isin(data['production'].nlargest(2))].index
data.loc[mask, 'production']  = data.production.mean()
data
```

So, for 'group'= A value 900 should be replaced with (420+390)/2 = 405

Comment: You are missing a comma after the "production" list in your code.

Comment: Thank you that noticed. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Boolean indexing:

```py
is_outlier = data['production'] >= data['production'].sort_values(ascending=False).iat[1]

clipped_group_means = data[~is_outlier].groupby('group').mean()

for group in set(data.group):
    data.loc[np.logical_and(is_outlier, data.group == group), 'production'] = \
        clipped_group_means.production[group]
    
data
```

```
    production  group
0   420.0       A
1   405.0       A
2   390.0       A
3   500.0       B
4   555.0       B
5   527.5       B
```

If there is a tie for the second largest value, then you may have to modify this code according to how many outliers you want to replace in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this is what you're looking for:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "production": [420, 900, 390, 500, 555, 700],
    "group": ['A','A','A','B','B','B']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

maxA = max(df[df['group'] == 'A']['production'])
maxB = max(df[df['group'] == 'B']['production'])

meanA = sum(df[df['group'] == 'A']['production']) / len(df[df['group'] == 'A']['production'])
meanB = sum(df[df['group'] == 'B']['production']) / len(df[df['group'] == 'B']['production'])

df = df.replace(maxA, meanA)
df = df.replace(maxB, meanB)

print (df)
```

Comment: It seems that you code takes the largest values in mean calculation, however, these values should be ignored in mean calculations. and I was looking for a solution that tries to calculate values without implicitly stating df['group'] == 'B', but more about identify row indexes with loc() and then do calculations